# How do you filter get_media_items by mime type in a custom media upload tab?

Tags: plugin-development, media-library, uploads

I've gotten as far as creating my new tab and getting it to show up and I've taken a copy of the gallery screen (I'm making an audio plugin with a playlist feature). The list of media items shows up fine but I can only get it to show just the audio files when I don't pass a post ID into the `get_media_items()` function like in the media library tab.

How I can retrieve a media items list using `get_media_items()` where the post_parent field is set and the post_mime_type matches 'audio'?

Comment: I believe you would use the function get_children http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_children

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer ended up being to copy that function and filter the results it returned. It's hacky but until there are more hooks/filters available in that section of the core there's no better way :(